# How do you divide the rows of one table with the rows of another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, math, division

If I have two tables of integer values like:

```
Table:Distance
1
2
3
4
5

Table:Time
2
4
6
8
10
```

How do I divide the Table:Distance by Table:Time to achieve

```
Result:
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
```

Comment: You need another column in both tables to join on. There is no default ordering of rows (unless you want both `Time` and `Distance` ordered ascending?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Time and Distance have some kind of relationship.

```
select Distance.value / CAST(Time.value As float)
from Distance 
join Time on Distance.ID = Time.ID
```

The cast to `float` is needed if `Time.value` or `Distance.value` is an `integer` to get the result as a `float`.
If you have no relationship between the tables you should [create one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You need a column in common between the tables to know which rows in one table match with the rows in another table.  Let's say you added an id column to both tables so you had

**Table Distance:**

```
id     distance
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5         5
```

**Table Time:**

```
id     time
1       2
2       4
3       6
4       8
5       10
```

Then you could do something like this

```
SELECT (Distance.distance/CAST(Time.time As Float)) As Result
FROM Distance INNER JOIN time ON Distance.id = Time.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 1-1 relationship between time and distance, and if you can redefine the table structures, it would be better to define both time and distance in the same table.